# Losing Model after posting ajax form MVC Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm pretty new to understanding Razor Pages and I am having an issue with retrieving model data after a form has been posted. It is able to retrieve the data on page load but as soon as I post the form, the model is null. This is a part of a large company project so it's difficult for me to post all of the data, but here's the relevant snippet of the code:

```
@inherits ViewPage<ViewModels.User.SignUp.VerifyActivationCodeModel>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(nameof(SignUpController.VerifyActivationCode),
    SignUpController.ControllerName, null, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "VerifyActivationCodePage.OnSuccess",
        OnFailure = "ErrorHelper.HandleError"
    }, new { id = "verifyActivationCodeForm", autocomplete = "off" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="">
        <div class="">
            <h3 class="">
                @Html.Raw(Model.Title)
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <div class="">
            <fieldset class="form-row">
                @Html.TextBoxSensitiveFor(m => m.ActivationCode,
                    new
                    {
                       placeholder = string.Format(ResourceManager.GetResource("VerifyToken"), Model.Token),
                       @class = "in-text",
                       maxlength = "100"
                    })

 // rest of form ...
```

When I post this form, the Model.Token that I am trying to populate as a placeholder is 'Null', whereas before posting it successfully populates from Resources.

Is anyone able to help? Thanks

Comment: Add @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Token) inside your form, and see if it helps.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much @KevinAmorim!

Comment: Nice! Posted it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind the data back to your action you should have them in your form.

For fields you don't want to show on your form you can use:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FieldName)
```

This way they will bind back to your action, but will not show on your form.